# How to add dynamic components/partials in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to add child components dynamically to a component based on user interaction. I looked to some [old issue](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254) but it seems like a dirty hack to me, besides, it is an old issue, and vue development is really active, so I don't know if there is some better approach now.

What I've tried so far is here on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5n5z5oo/1/)  but is obviously not working, it says that `$mount` can only be called once. I don't know how to do it, my other option would be dynamic component, but for that I would also have to add a `<component>` element dynamically so it turns to be almost the same issue.

So how could I add a component on client click or other client event?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to put the custom components there right from the start, and use `v-if` or `v-for` to show, hide, add, or subtract these components.  You let the data drive the DOM, not managing the DOM yourself.  Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/f5n5z5oo/2/

You can even make the components dynamically change what type of component they are using `is`:

```
data: {
  elements: [
    { type: 'component-a' },
    { type: 'component-b' }
  ]
}
<div v-for="element in elements" :is="element.type"></div>
```

If you're more specific about your use case I will try to help further!

Comment: As always is much easier than what I though :) thanks for the hint on `v-for` with this I also have access to the `$index` and solve my oncoming next problem, awesome. This is how my fiddle looks like now, with data and props, using the `$index` value https://jsfiddle.net/f5n5z5oo/3/ thanks again

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps someone in future : There are numerous methods of doing this , below is one way of doing this :

**1.** If component is already defined , simply adding a new instance of component importantly using `parent` keyword to define parent of component instance  as below : check [codepen](http://codepen.io/obonyojimmy/pen/ONwKZX)

```
var Child = Vue.extend({
    template: '<div>Hello!</div>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  ready: function() {
    var child = new Child({
        el: this.$el.querySelector('.child-host'),
        parent: this,
    });
  },
});
```