# vue js dynamically create components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

am trying to create a dynamic component in a defined component as below :

main component ( should dynamically create the component `extform-input` when called )

```
...
components: {
       'extform-input' : ExtformInput

    },
methods : {
      changeType: function () {
       var self = this 
      var TheComponent = this.$options.components['extform-input'];
      self.$addChild(TheComponent);
}

...
```

i get error `self.$addChild is not a function`

Comment: Are you sure `vm.$addChild` is still in vue 1.0? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If component is already mounted ie defined as a component globally using `Vue(tag,constructor)` then simply adding a new instance of component importantly using `parent` keyword to define parent of component instance will do the trick as below :

NB : As of vue js V-1.0.12, `$addChild` method was removed

```
components: {
    'extform-input' : ExtformInput
},
methods : {
    changeType: function() {
        var self = this 
        var Child = this.$options.components['extform-input'];
        var child = new Child({
            el: this.$el.querySelector('.child-host'), \\ define the el of component
            parent: this, \\ define parent of component
        });
    }
}
```

See codepen demo http://codepen.io/obonyojimmy/pen/ONwKZX

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically instantiate components in Vue js. Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254) about the subject, and a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927664/how-to-add-dynamic-components-partials-in-vue-js) (I did that question). But, even if you can't dynamically add components, you can do what you want to do, in a different way. Instead of adding the child, you have to show it adding it to the DOM, if you want to add a single component use `v-if` (notiche that you are not hidding/showing an element, you are adding/removing from the DOM). And if you want to add a variable number of component on the fly, use `v-for`. The details are on the referenced question for the `v-for` way

Comment: Acctully you can i have managed it kindly check this github discussion https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2719 and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qsm2axry/

Comment: You are right, then you should add it as the answer for others looking for it

Comment: sure will just finishing up with something then add it as answer ,